# How to toggle class to each li element in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

How to toggle class to parent `li` element when click child button.

Also `li` element is dynamic item.

This is what I tried so far

```
export default function About() { 
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(); 
  return (
    <ul className="list"> 
      <li className={`list-item ${show ? "on" : ""}`} >
        <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
          Toggle
        </button> 
      </li>
      <li className={`list-item ${show ? "on" : ""}`} >
        <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
          Toggle
        </button> 
      </li> 
    </ul>
  );
}
```

The problem is when click the button, all `li` toggle together. I want them toggle seperatly.

Please help.

Comment: what's wrong with the solution you have tried so far?

Comment: The problem is when click the button, all li toggle together.  I want them toggle seperatly.

Comment: It looks like you have 1 variable, `show`, to keep track of the state for `N` number of `<li>`'s. Do you see the issue?

If each `<li>` needs to have its own state, that could be a good sign you need to create a new component, perhaps `<ListItem />`? This way, each `<ListItem />` will have its own `useState` hook to handle the state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 1 variable, `show`, to keep track of the state for `N` number of `<li>`'s. Do you see the issue?

If each `<li>` needs to have its own state, that could be a good sign you need to create a new component, perhaps `<ListItem />`? This way, each `<ListItem />` will have its own `useState` hook to handle the state changes.

```js
function About() {
  return (
    <ul className="list">
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
    </ul>
  );
}

function ListItem() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <li className={`list-item ${show ? "on" : ""}`}>
      <button onClick={() => setShow(prev => !prev)}>Toggle</button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try list?

```
export default function About() { 
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = React.useState(null);
  const list = ['Toggle', 'Toggle']
  
  const onBtnClick = (index) => {
    if (activeId === index) {
      setActiveId(null)
    } else {
      setActiveId(index)
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <ul className="list"> 
      {list.map((item, idx) => (
        <li key={idx} className={`list-item ${activeId === idx ? "on" : ""}`} >
          <button onClick={() => onBtnClick(idx)}>
            {item}
          </button> 
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to toggle separately, you need two separate `show` state variables.

Try this:

```
export default function About() { 
  const [showA, setShowA] = React.useState(); 
  const [showB, setShowB] = React.useState(); 
  return (
    <ul className="list"> 
      <li className={`list-item ${showA ? "on" : ""}`} >
        <button onClick={() => setShowA((orig) => !orig)}>
          Toggle
        </button> 
      </li>
      <li className={`list-item ${showB ? "on" : ""}`} >
        <button onClick={() => setShowB((orig) => !orig)}>
          Toggle
        </button> 
      </li> 
    </ul>
  );
}
```